# Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63

Tags: checkout, error

My checkout suddenly goes to a white page, it never used to do this!

The error I am getting is

> Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php
>   on line 63

PLEASE HELP! Thank you very much

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be caused by a recent upgrade to PHP and you are missing [PHP Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) module.

To install it's usually a simple `apt-get install php5-mcrypt` on Ubuntu/Debian. A Google search should turn up the correct instructions for your PHP and OS version.

http://aryo.lecture.ub.ac.id/easy-install-php-mcrypt-extension-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, is there a command I can install this with on Ubuntu server 12?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: i have face same issue in few days ago. its php5-mcrypt missing issue

Comment: TIL you may need to run `php5enmod mcrypt` on some systems after installing mcrypt via the system's package manager.

Comment: If `apt-get install php5-mcrypt` doesn't work, you can try `apt-get install php53-mcrypt`.

Comment: The new updates to php5-mcrypt do not auto-enable, even if included in the mods-enabled directory. After the module is installed and included, the command: `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` must be called

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases, this issue comes in php updated version i.e. `php7` and if `mcrypt` is not installed -

to install it, follow the below steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: My current version of the PHP is 7.2.3, So i followed the command sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.2-mcrypt, but the package is not found error am getting