# Magento Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() using WampServer

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, server-setup, wamp, mcrypt

I am using Magento 1, installed on a **Windows 10 php(7.2) WampServer**.

[image]

I tried to add this **extension=php_mcrypt.dll** in **php.ini**, but continued to receive the error.

[image]

How to add **extension=php_mcrypt.dll** in **Windows 10** to resolve this error?

Comment: what is your magento version if it is below the 2.2.3 then php 7.2 will not supported for them

Answer (score 0):

After installed extension=php_mcrypt.dll, have you restarted the Apache?
If not please do it, then check.

Or you can follow these steps.

[Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35887/call-to-undefined-function-mcrypt-module-open-in-lib-varien-crypt-mcrypt-php-o)

Comment: i already read this article but there no solution for on window users